# Multiple users editting widgets

Tags: widgets, admin

I have just completed a website using WordPress as a CMS, the site has 6 people administering the content and in the couple of days before launch all 6 were updating the content.

We found that if multiple people were editing/creating widgets at the same time this would save over and some of the widgets were deleted. I'm assuming this is because widgets are stored in a serialized array when the user is pressing save its adding an array which doesn't contain the widget the another user is editing.

Obviously this can be a bit frustrating for the users so I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if there was a way to only allow one user to edit widgets at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never personally had this problem, but to the best of my knowledge WordPress does not have the system to support multiple users managing widgets at the same time, at least not widgets in the same widget areas.

Is it a problem to just have one user at a time manage the widgets? I can't really imagine that being a problem, as 99% of the time you set widgets once and don't change them for extended periods of time.

If the site requires that widgets be frequently (more than once per day), then I would seriously consider improving the site infrastructure to NOT require this. Use posts, pages, or custom post types to hold the content and widgets to display the items.

Comment: +1 for this. These users need to be communicating with each other.

Comment: No it shouldn't really be a problem as the widget content won't be updated that regularly. I just found it an odd problem and I can't have been the only person to find this and was hoping someone may have come across a solution for it.